# Count worktime for current month only

Tags: excel

I would like to ask for a bit of help, as I can't figure it out myself.

What I would like to end up is, get the total calculation of the work time hours for each name only for the month written in A5 cell.

So far I used this code to have the start date Monday, based on the date in A5 cell.

```
=A5-MOD(A5-2,7)
```

With this community help I ended up with this code to count the work time for each name in the week (lots of students in the schedule)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(MID(C7:H7,FIND("-",C7:H7,1)+1,LEN(C7:H7)-FIND("-",C7:H7,1))) - TIMEVALUE(LEFT(C7:H7,FIND("-",C7:H7,1)-1)),0))
```

The help I need, if it's possible, is to figure out how to get the total work time only for the month entered in cell A5 (which is 1.october - 31.october) without counting the last 3 days in September. I plan to use this spreadsheet for the following months as well. I tried to use COUNTIFS, but no luck so far. Also, I am using an online excel version, which is very limited in the menu.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: work schedule]

Answer (score 0):

=TEXT(c6, "mmm") will give Sep, while TEXT(A5, "mmm") will give Oct. You need to SUMIF the month matches.

You could incorporate this together with the equation you already have but I think it might be easier to create a duplicate table below the main table, copying the day of the month and the names and using your above mentioned equation to get the hours to be summed.
Either above or below the date, or instead of the date, I'd pull out the month with =TEXT(C6, "mmm")

Lets say the duplicate table for cells B16-I12 was in cells B106-I112 with the extra row specifying the month above this in row 105 (=TEXT(C106, "mmm") etc.).

Then in cell D24, you'd have
=SUMIF(C$105:I$105,TEXT($A$5,"mmm"),C107:I107) +[same again for the next week, cells B15-I21] + [same again for the next week] etc.
This can then be copied down for all the names.

You could also feed this information up into cells K7, K8,K12, becuase you only need this for the first and last months. So J6 would read 'hours this week' K6 would read Hours last month, L6, hours this month. Then D24 could sum L7 and J16 etc.

Comment: thanks for the help. The problem here I have is because I have times example 7:00-15:00 and not in 2 different cells. That's why as in my original post i use to code to calculate with SUMPRODUCT(TIMEVALUE).. I don't know how to combine this with your code, because otherwise it gives me result 0.